# Erro de Overload C#

Tags: c#

Estou com o seguinte erro  CS0123   No overload for 'lsvRecebeGrupoLayout_ItemCheck' matches delegate 'ItemCheckEventHandler' no código abaixo, alguma sugestão do que pode estar causando esse erro?

```
private void lsvRecebeGrupoLayout_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e, CheckBox cb)
{
    GrupoLayout gp = new GrupoLayout();
    RepositorioGrupoLayout r = new RepositorioGrupoLayout();
    Layout lay = new Layout();
    cb.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(gp.Id);
    lay.Id = Convert.ToInt32(cb.Checked);
    r.Alterar(lay.GrupoLayout);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque seu `lsvRecebeGrupoLayout_ItemCheck` é um método cuja assinatura não é válida para ser um handler do evento `ItemCheck`.

Segundo a [especificação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx), a assinatura do método deve conter apenas `object` e `ItemCheckEventArgs`

***Como resolver?***

Remova o `Checkbox cb` da assinatura. Você não precisa dele ali, pois ele é seu `sender`, basta fazer um cast:

`var cb = (CheckBox)sender;`

Comment: matou o erro, muito obrigado Artur. #PAZ

Comment: @Anderson, se a resposta atendeu bem, marca ela como aceita ;)

Comment: Estava esperando o tempo acabar :)

Comment: Estou tentando pegar um ID de uma checkbox do list view, porém não estou conseguindo, aproveitando a deixa. Alguma dica de como fazer isso? o Código está assim: 
   private void lsvRecebeGrupoLayout_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
var cb = (CheckBox)sender;
GrupoLayout gp = new GrupoLayout();
RepositorioGrupoLayout r = new RepositorioGrupoLayout();
Layout lay = new Layout();
if (cb.Checked)
{
 cb.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(gp.Id);
 lay.Id = Convert.ToInt32(cb.Checked);
.Alterar(lay.GrupoLayout);
}
}